# How to persist Objects with the same parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to build a "world" consisting of Fields

for simplicity lets say there is a water and town field

i created two classes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Water extends Field {

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Town extends Field {

}
```

and used @MappedSuperclass like so

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Field {
    private long x;
    private long y;
}
```

This works ... but
if i want to create a town now i will have to check if there is already something on that field in my world. This is sort of fine as long as there are only water and town fields
but if i imagine to have more types i will have to create a lot of repositories and do a query to each of them to see if there is a town at x:y or a water at x:y or whatever at x:y

i am searching for a nicer way to persist "this world"

Comment: My feeling is that you should be choosing a better aggregate root for your repository, either a world or a block with a limited x-y range so that acts like a collection of fields (https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html "A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection"), but don't know any jpa.

Comment: thanks, the question is pretty java jpa heavy i was not sure if asking it here was right we will see, the repositories are jpa's way of accessing the database and doing the ORM magic, i will look into your link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Discriminator](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_discrim.html) concept.

By following this approach, you can store different field types in a single table, and when querying, you will receive a list of Field objects. You can determine the specific type of each field using the discriminator column and perform type-specific operations as needed.

So, using the example you provided, you should:

1. Remove the **@MappedSuperclass** annotation from the *Field* class since it's not needed.
2. Create a single repository, let's say *FieldRepository*, to handle the persistence and retrieval of all field types.
3. Modify the *Field* class to include a discriminator column that identifies the type of each field with the **@DiscriminatorColumn** annotation. Additionally, annotate the *Field* class with **@Entity**.
4. Create concrete subclasses for each field type (e.g., *Water* and *Town*) and annotate them with **@Entity** and **@DiscriminatorValue**.
5. Use the *FieldRepository* to query fields by location.

Comment: thanks for the hint of Discriminator Concept especially for jpa!